# How to download all files from GitHub release?

Tags: git, github, github-release

I am looking at a GitHub release that contains over 200 .tgz files that I want to download. Is there any way to download them all in bulk within one line/script, as opposed to downloading them each individually?

Because it is not exactly hosted on the GitHub repository, I can't clone the master repository either. How should I go about this efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

The github [cli](https://github.com/cli/cli) (gh) can be used for this. [Here](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download) are the docs.

This is for downloading all files (github release assets) from a specific github release.

```bash
gh release list -R <username>/<repo>
gh release download <tag> -D <dest> -R <username>/<repo>

# for eg.
gh release list -R cli/cli
gh release download v2.21.2 -D gh_v2.21.2 -R cli/cli

# download all assets from latest release to gh_latest directory
gh release download -p "*" -D gh_latest -R cli/cli
```

*Note:*

- If you are in a git repository, `gh release download <tag>` will download all the assets from the latest release to the current directory.
  No need to specify `-R` `-D`.
- If the tag is not specified, it will download the latest release but complain that one of the `-A or -p` flags is required. In such case `gh release download -p "*"` can be used.
- Check the examples in the [docs](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download) for more.

Comment: Here's a way to download the latest release `gh release download -R raaka/cpp \`gh release list -R raaka/cpp -L 1| awk '{print $5}'\`` until https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2310 is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GitHub API to get a list of releases and to download each release by tag name.

Reference:

- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-releases
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-by-tag-name